# How to check last login and logout time of users on Windows Vista?

Tags: windows, windows-vista

Is it possible to check the last login and logout time of users on Windows Vista?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible. You can see that in the event viewer. There is a view for user events, system events and so on... As I am a mac user, I can't check that now. Also you can see the last logout of a user in his profile folder, as that is written back to the HDD when the user logs off.